# Google Maps Cluster + Prevent Zoom & De-Cluster on Click

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following code:

```
       markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(this.map, allMarkers, {
            imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m',
            minimumClusterSize: 2,
            maxZoom: 0,
            zoomOnClick: false
        });
```

I need to prevent Zoom on a click and this is working fine.

I'm looking to uncluster a Cluster when click on without changing the zoom level. Essentially this is hiding the cluster icon with the click.

Is there a way to do this or is the zoom required?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [MarkerClustererPlus](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclustererplus), you can do something like this:

```
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers, {
  imagePath: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m',
  minimumClusterSize: 2,
  maxZoom: 0,
  zoomOnClick: false
});
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'click', function(clust) {
    for (var i = 0; i < clust.getMarkers().length; i++) {
      clust.getMarkers()[i].setMap(map);
    }
    clust.remove();
});
```

Which will display the markers from the clicked cluster and remove the cluster from the map.  Unless you do additional coding, the clusters will reform when you zoom the map.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q1j0o0t/1/)